# Netezza: How to convert varchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, netezza

I have a `VARCHAR` column named `FECHAATENDIDO` with data in different formats, for example:

```
2013-07-04
14/08/2012
20080522
```

I need a query to obtain the year and month. This is how it was done in SQL Server:

```
SELECT product, year(fechaatendido) as year, month(fechaatendido) as month
FROM consulta where YEAR(fechaatendido)=2013;
```

How can I do the same with Netezza?

Answer (score 1):

```
select consulta.FECHAATENDIDO
,date(consulta.FECHAATENDIDO) as date_FECHAATENDIDO
from (select cast('2013-07-04' as varchar(20)) as FECHAATENDIDO
union all
select cast('14/08/2012' as varchar(20))
union all
select cast('20080521' as varchar(20))
) consulta
where date_part('year',date(consulta.FECHAATENDIDO))=2013
```